# Not able to receive GCM message in my device, even though the server got success message

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I got success message as response to web server (localhost) from gcm. But the message is not received by the devices. Please help. Below is the code which I used.

**Main Activity**

```
package vitpat.placement;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.app.Activity;    
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";

    TextView textUnderProgressBar;
    String SENDER_ID = "794097343372";
    final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
    TextView mDisplay;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;
    String regid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        textUnderProgressBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        //shared preference to check if the application is being run for the first time and the user is yet to be verified
        SharedPreferences prefToVerifyUser = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
        Boolean isUserVerified = prefToVerifyUser.getBoolean("UserVerified", false);
        Log.e("main activity", isUserVerified.toString());
        if(isUserVerified == false) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,Check_User_Authentication.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
        else {
        //end of shared preference check

        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Check device for Play Services APK.
        if(CheckForPlayStoreApp()) {
            //code
            textUnderProgressBar.setText("Contacting Server..");
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);
            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            }
            else {
                textUnderProgressBar.setText(regid.toString());
                /*GcmBroadcastReceiver gcr;
                GcmBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService(getApplicationContext(), getIntent());*/

            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean CheckForPlayStoreApp() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i("CheckForPlayStoreApp", "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // You need to do the Play Services APK check here too.
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        CheckForPlayStoreApp();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }
    /**
     * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
     */
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences.
     */
    private void registerInBackground() {
        Log.e("inside register", "sample0");
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                Log.e("inside register", "sample1");
                  String msg = "";
                    try {
                        if (gcm == null) {
                            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                        }
                        regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                        Log.e("inside register", regid);
                        msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                        // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                        // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                        // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                        // is using accounts.
                        sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                        // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                        // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                        // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                        // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                        storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                        // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                        // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                        // exponential back-off.
                    }

                return null;
            }


        }.execute(null, null, null);

    }

    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP
     * or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the
     * device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the message
     * using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
        private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        // Your implementation here.
        String url = "http://192.168.43.112/dist/addregistrationid.php";

        SharedPreferences prefUserDetails = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("UserDetails", 0);
        String registerNumber = prefUserDetails.getString("registerNumber", null);


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid", regid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regno", registerNumber));
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }         
    }

    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param regId registration ID
     */
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }


}
```

**GcmBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),GcmIntentService.class.getName());
            // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
         startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
         setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);


    }

}
```

**GcmIntentService**

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    Context context;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

         if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

             if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                            extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                        MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    // Post notification of received message.
                    //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                    sendNotification(msg);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                }
            }
         GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ReceiveActivity.class);
        myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
       // .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());


    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="vitpat.placement"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="vitpat.placement.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="vitpat.placement.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="vitpat.placement.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="vitpat.placement.Check_User_Authentication"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="vitpat.placement" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="vitpat.placement.ReceiveActivity"></activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I was using the "**android api key**" to send the message from my web server (php) to gcm server and that was the problem. Using "**browser api**" key solved the issue..
Create a new "**browser api key**" from google console and use it in the php code to send a message from web server to gcm.

If you want to send a message from android device to gcm, try using android key.
Make sure, you create all these keys from the same project under google console.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem of receiving push messages, even though GCM server replies "Success", because of wifi privacy. When I used my company wifi, I coudn't receive message in mobile, since they were blocked GCM server port . So, even your wifi also could be a one of the reason. check it once { this answer is for others , who may face this}