# Not receiving push notifications on Android when I'm connected to my Wifi

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

So, I'm facing a problem with my Samsung Galaxy s5 (sm-g900f). I can't receive push notifications for some apps (hangouts, whatsapp, gmail,..apparently all the apps using Google Cloud Messaging to push their notifications). I'm having this problem when I'm connected to my home Wifi only; when I turn off the wifi and switch to mobile data, all the delayed notifications arrive all at once. However, when I connect to other Wifis, everything seems to be working normal. Also note that, other phones work normally on my wifi (Samung galaxy s4 for instance). I've already done some troubleshooting:

1) I was using the stock android 5.0 (the Spain firmware) (I live in Lebanon) . I rooted my phone, the problem remained. I put a custom rom , didn't solve anything. Finally ,I unrooted the phone and I fully wiped it and installed the stock android kitkat (4.4.2) for Lebanon from sammobile.com, again with no luck.

2) I thought it was a router issue, so I changed my router.

3) I downloaded "push notification fixer".

4) I looked up the ports that GCM (google cloud messaging) uses, and I forwarded those ports to my phone's local IP.

Nothing of the steps mentioned made any difference. I'm sure there are still some troubleshooting I haven't tried; Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problems after I reset my phone. Twice. And a reset for my router.
Even more, couldn't open gmail folders or receive Skype notifications on time.
Long story short, in "Menu>Security>Apps with usage access" I had Google Play Services unchecked.

So, make sure that Google Play Services is active.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

- Try to NOT 
  include `delay_while_idle`
- Set `time_to_live` to a reasonable value
- Try to hold a Wi-Fi lock in your app
- Test with    different device    and/or Android version; does it cause problem to only one device or to other devices as well?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this spending hours searching.  Almost identical problems on my S4.  I downloaded "[ROOT] Disable IPv6" from the app store and it fixed my issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem no matter which network I was connected to.

It was solved by enabling the OS-wide time synchronization with the cellular network provider (it was disabled for some weird reason).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem upgrading gcm library to com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.8.0

Answer (score 0):

If you have Lollipop you might try going to Settings -> Apps, then swipe right. There might be a tab there called "restricted". If there is, go to it, and then uncheck whatever apps you are using. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this problem.

today i resolve this!

i installed a `vpn` software that in settings , "receive notification" was unchecked.

i set check this option and once run vpn then disconnect.

now I've not problem!

try this if u have Similar App , maybe helpful.

Too watch[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969732/do-not-receive-gcm-message-while-android-device-beeing-connected-to-wifi) : [Do not receive GCM message while android device beeing connected to WIFI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969732/do-not-receive-gcm-message-while-android-device-beeing-connected-to-wifi)

Good luck.